# Using Meteor.renderList inside a template throwing errors

Tags: meteor

i tried to use `Meteor.renderList` to render some sort of chat messages. I use the `Template.foo.rendered` callback method to add the domFragment to a list.

```coffeescript
Template.foo.rendered = ->
    list = this.find "ul"
    list.appendChild fragmet
```

If I place the list inside `<template name="foo">` Meteor throws errors in an endless loop/recursion.

```
Uncaught Error: LiveRange start and end must have a parent
```

I have to use another template thats not directly connected to `foo`. Appending the list from within the `foo#rendered` callback than works as expected.

```coffeescript
Template.foo.rendered = ->
    document.getElementById("foo").appendChild fragmet # element with id foo not part of template foo
```

I think, that there is a problem with the reactive contextes used by the template and `renderList`? Anyone knows if this is a bug or the expected behavior? I looked into the sources but was lost in there quite fast ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense because you are appending an element to the template when the template is rendered. So, every time the template is rendered, it appends an element to itself, causing it to re-render itself, ad infinitum.

Are you sure you want `Meteor.renderList` to render your list rather than using an `{{each}}` iterator in the template itself?